Export to excel with dynamic columns & values in .net C#
I have a dynamic grid in kendo the column names and column number changes will be different based on conditions.I am not able to export since it is a dynamic list
I have provided the code below
.cshtml
$(".download").click(function () {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var options = {
            format: $(this).data("format"),
            title: 'Testreport'
        }
        var parsedInput = GetInputDataTransfer();
        var ChkBoxvalues = parsedInput.InputChkBoxValues;
        $("#export-data").val(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(options)));
        $("#export-model").val(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(grid.columns)));
        $("#export-chkbox").val(ChkBoxvalues);
        $("#export-tabId").val(currentTabId);  
    });

Controller action method:
when i try to convert my list to excel it throws object reference error
public FileStreamResult ExportServer(string model, string data, string selectedInputChkBoxValues, string tabId)
        {
            try
            {
                string projnumber = (string)Session[$"projectSelection_{tabId}"];
                GetProjectDetails(projnumber);
                UserInfo uInfo = ApplicationData.GetUserInfoFromSession();
                ProjectDetails CurrentProject = uInfo.CurrentProject;
                string ProjectNo = Convert.ToString(CurrentProject);
                DataSet dataSet = PLDeliveryViewBL.Display(ProjectNo, selectedInputChkBoxValues);
                var dcolumns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<ExportColumnSettings>>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(model));
                // Minimal column settings
                var columnsData = dcolumns.ToList();    

                List<dynamic> dlist = new List<dynamic>();
                if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dcolumns != null)
                {
                    for (var rowCount = 0; rowCount < dataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Count; rowCount++)
                    {
                        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
                        var objDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;

                        foreach (var column in dcolumns)
                        {
                           
                            string columnName = column.Field; 
                            objDict[columnName] = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[rowCount][columnName];
                        }

                        dlist.Add(obj);
                    }
                }

               // Minimal options
                dynamic options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data));
                string title = options["title"].ToString();
                string format = options["format"].ToString();  

                // Call the method to generate the stream
                Stream exportStream = null;
                try
                {
                   
                    exportStream = dlist.ToXlsxStream(columnsData, title);
                   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                 
                    throw;
                }

                // Prepare the result
                SpreadDocumentFormat exportFormat = SpreadDocumentFormat.Xlsx;
                string fileName = $"{title}.{format}";

                string mimeType = Helpers.GetMimeType(exportFormat);
                var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(exportStream, mimeType)
                {
                    FileDownloadName = fileName
                };
                fileStreamResult.FileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                return fileStreamResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                throw;
            }
        }

Kendo export class :
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Telerik.Documents.SpreadsheetStreaming;

namespace Kendo.Mvc.Export
{
    public static class ExportExtensions
    {
        public static Stream ToXlsxStream(this IEnumerable instance, IList<ExportColumnSettings> model, string title = "Sheet", Action<ExportColumnStyle> columnStyleAction = null, Action<ExportRowStyle> rowStyleAction = null, Action<ExportCellStyle> cellStyleAction = null)
        {
            return Helpers.CollectionToStream(SpreadDocumentFormat.Xlsx, instance, model, title, columnStyleAction, rowStyleAction, cellStyleAction);
        }

        public static Stream ToCsvStream(this IEnumerable instance, IList<ExportColumnSettings> model)
        {
            return Helpers.CollectionToStream(SpreadDocumentFormat.Csv, instance, model);
        }
    }
}

Error Thrown :
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Kendo.Mvc.Export
  StackTrace:
   at Kendo.Mvc.Export.Helpers.ExtractItemValue(Object dataItem, String propertyName)
   at Kendo.Mvc.Export.Helpers.CollectionToStream(SpreadDocumentFormat format, IEnumerable data, IList`1 model, String title, Action`1 columnStyleAction, Action`1 rowStyleAction, Action`1 cellStyleAction)
   at Kendo.Mvc.Export.ExportExtensions.ToXlsxStream(IEnumerable instance, IList`1 model, String title, Action`1 columnStyleAction, Action`1 rowStyleAction, Action`1 cellStyleAction)
   at DSWeb2._0.Controllers.DelPLController.ExportServer(String model, String data, String selectedInputChkBoxValues, String tabId) in C:\DSWEB\RegressionTesting_Solution_12thAug2024\RegressionTesting_Solution_6thAug2024\DSWeb2.0\Controllers\DelPLController.cs:line 205


Any solution can be provided?

Hi, could you provide the actual error? Otherwise I would suggest you add null checks.

When you debug, where exactly is it throwing? There are various places it could throw due to a lack of null checks, such as dataSet.Tables.Count.

Dataset has values i checked its count ,the line am getting error is  exportStream = dlist.Take(1).ToXlsxStream(columnsData, title);  it throws error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Are you sure dList has values at the point you're trying to take 1?

even if i dont use Take(1) when i try to export all like this code exportStream = dlist.ToXlsxStream(columnsData, title); still get the same error

Yes, because if dList is empty it has nothing to use in ToXlsxStream.

the case its not empty

var c = new List{new ExportColumnSettings { Title = "OU Name", Hidden = false, Field = "OUId_OUname" },};
List lst= new List();if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0){ for (var r = 0; r < dataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Count; r++)
{lst.Add(new {OUId_OUname = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[rowCount]["OUId_OUname"],});}}   - this code is working  i can export the objects in the list but if i try to do with dynamic columns as i mentioned in the code I am getting the object reference error even if the dlist has value
